# Angular always redirecting to index page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I visiting this url `http://localhost/calls`, but duaring angular loads my url changes to `http://localhost/`. There is no 'Location' in http headers

Route tracing:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/"}
core.umd.js:2957 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
platform-browser.umd.js:1060 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:''))
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 RoutesRecognized {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.umd.js:1060 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:''))
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 GuardsCheckStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.umd.js:1060 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:''), shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.umd.js:1060 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
platform-browser.umd.js:1051 NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}
```

Full routes as requested:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { CallOperatorAuthComponent } from './auth/call-operator-auth/call-operator-auth.component'
import { CallOperatorAuthGuard } from './auth/call-operator-auth/call-operator-auth.guard'
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'


// TODO: try later implement lazy loading again
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: CallOperatorAuthComponent},
    {
        path: 'calls',
        component: CallsComponent,
        canActivate: [ CallOperatorAuthGuard ]
    },
]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } )
```

Angular 4.4.3

**EDIT** This is my canActivate:

```
canActivate() {
  if (this.localStorage.get('user')) {
    return true
  } 
  this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]) return false;
}
```

Comment: what is that: `children: callsRoutes,`??

Comment: show Your `callsRoutes` object

Comment: Oh, I deleted that string when testing and posting to here. It doesn't matter. First time I thought something is wrong with children too

Comment: If You can show full `Routes` file

Comment: are You using `wildcard` into You `routes`; like: `path: "**"`

Comment: No (this path I deleted too)

Comment: Are you getting any error in console. Most of time if angular got rendering error, it redirect to root url.

Comment: No any errors in console

Comment: I think without code sharing we couldn't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out a reason. I inject service and in its constructor was redirect to '/'.
Thanks everyone for helping.